AMD graphics issues
I did something to my machine and can't seem to fix it. I have followed probably 20 different forum posts about similar issues and have maybe partially fixed the issue but issues keep cropping up so I am finally here out of desperation (I don't want to have to completely reinstall my OS)
So here is the series of things I have done...

tried to install amdgpu-pro for ROCM support. Found out after installing that my current kernel version (v6.6.12 at the time) isn't supported yet.
ran amdgpu-uninstall to clean it out, restarted
graphics were all broken now
added 'amdgpu' to my /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
Updated kernel to newer version (6.7.10)
ran 'modprobe amdgpu' and updated initramfs and updated grub and restarted, everything seemed fine after this! Games worked, desktop applications worked, etc.

Today I did a apt update/upgrade and noticed a bunch of stuff that needed to be removed so

I did 'apt autoremove'... and now my graphics are messing up again.
I realized that I needed to delete '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf' which blacklisted the GPU (how was it loading before!?)
On restart I now get weird flashing white screen, but then the desktop loads. The drivers show they are loaded. However, many applications won't show/run anymore. I maybe due to a missing wayland package? I am also using pipewire (having upgraded from pulseaudio a few months ago)

I suspect that I have accidentally removed a package during the autoremove that I needed but I have no clue which package it was and how to find it. -- EDIT: This is not the core issue.
Is there a way to just force a reinstall of all standard amdgpu libraries?
EDIT: Found the packages I removed and only 2 were able to be reinstalled. Installed them, restarted, problem persists.
One thing to note (not sure if important) I am using kisak ppa for mesa/wayland https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa
I really want to just like... reset the entire mesa/wayland/x/amdgpu stack back to how it was on install.

I found the things I removed
libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
gst-omx-amdgpu:amd64 (1:1.0.0.1.60002...
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
libwayland-amdgpu-client0:amd64 (1.22.0.60002...
libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
libwayland-amdgpu-server0:amd64 (1.22.0.60002...
xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu:amd64 (1:22.0.0.60002...
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:23.3.0.60002...
Reinstall-able:
libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64
libomxil-bellagio0:amd64

Found the issue. amdgpu-core was still installed and so was messing with the default amdgpu.
apt remove amdgpu-core and restarted and now everything is working as expected.
